# Google reCaptach on Spa - branding only on interested form

Tags: angular, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

I'm developing an Angular spa, and i wanted to add the google reCAPTCHA v3 service to protect some of my form.
I know that i can hide the recaptcha badge by including "the recaptcha branding visibly in the user flow", as stated in the faq.
Since **i'm just protecting a single form** , and not the entire application, i wonder if i'm allowed to put this message **ONLY below that single form** , and not on every "page" of my spa.
I'd like also to know if i'm allowed to translate this message based on user locale